# How to Customize the Conan Visual_Studio Generator Output File

Tags: conan

I am generating Visual Studio property files using Conan's visual_studio generator.  The resulting output from this generator is "conanbuildinfo.props".  Within this properties file, the following optional tag can be added to specify a display-name (VS2015):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_PropertySheetDisplayName>Custom Name</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to configure this generator to:

- Rename the generated output file from "conanbuildinfo.props" to something else, and
- Add a custom display name within the generated output file

Comment: Added an answer, hope it helps. For help and discussion, it is also possible to use github issues, and there is also a very active slack channel with lots of helpful users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensibility and customizations of generators is possible by creating your own generator:

- They are like a regular conan package you can put the code for the generator in a conanfile.py, upload and depend on it later to use it.
- The existing `visual_studio` builtin generator could be a good starting point, it can be copied from the codebase, then customized, including the output file name and its contents.

Find a [guide for creating custom generators here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/custom_generators.html#dyn-generators)